# Unslider - Responsive Height

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to use [Unslider](http://unslider.com/)  but am having difficulty getting the height to be automatic and responsive. It seems the height can't be changed, only the width can.

[here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6get43yv/1/)

```
.banner {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;

font-size: 18px;
line-height: 24px;
text-align: center;
background: #fff;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
height: auto;
}


.banner ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 300%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.banner ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;

}
```

Hopefully that's enough insight but please let me know if you need more code.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6get43yv/3/)

Try this

```
.banner {
    position: relative;
    width: 96%;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    height: auto;

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. The image inside adjusts to auto height, but the frame itself stays a fixed height still.